# In Visual Studio 2017 Visual Basic, I get an "End of statement expected" error

Tags: basic

In the following code, I get an "End of statement expected" and "'Text' is not a member of string" errors:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnFtoC_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFtoC.Click
        Try
            Dim f As Decimal CDec(txtF.Text)
            Dim c As Decimal
            Dim txtC As String

            c = 5 / 9 * (f - 32)
            txtC.Text = CStr(c)

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnFtoC_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFtoC.Click
        Try
            Dim f As Decimal CDec(txtF.Text)
            Dim c As Decimal
            Dim txtC As String

            c = 5 / 9 * (f - 32)
            txtC.Text = CStr(c)

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class

Comment: You're working with temperature so use `Double` (scientific values) and not `Decimal` (monetary values).

Comment: Also, learn now not to ever write `Catch ex As Exception`. You should only ever catch specific exceptions, that you can't code your way out of, and that you can meaningfully handle. You should **rarely** write an exception handler. Too many people use them too often and they just end up creating buggy code.

Comment: Try `Dim f As Decimal = CDec(txtF.Text)`

Comment: Also, make sure you have `Option Strict On` and `Option Explicit On` while coding in VB.NET. They'll make you a better coder.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared txtC as a `String` using `Dim txtC As String` so there is no `txtC.Text`.  (Perhaps you were intending to populate a textbox?)

Answer (score 0):

I assume txtF and txtC are text boxes. You need to test the input in the txtF to see if it is a valid `Decimal`.

```
Private Sub btnFtoC_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFtoC.Click
    Dim f As Decimal
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtF.Text, f) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number")
        Return
    End If
    Dim c = CDec(5 / 9 * (f - 32))
    txtC.Text = CStr(c)
End Sub
```